# Web.config URL Rewrite

Tags: c#, iis

I would like to rewrite all paths, except those that are real files or real directories, and `/api/*` to `~/Default.aspx`.

This is what I have so far:

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="default" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

The problem with this is that it rewrites `/api/*` to `Default.aspx` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
<rules>
  <rule name="api" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*api*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="None" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="default" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following condition:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="(?:\/api)" />
</conditions>
```